# Application Name is not correct ! Google Console?

Tags: java, android

I have a big big problem...

I created an application on android and i published it firstly under the name : "Flappy Pinkie".

Then i changed my application design etc... and i wanted to change also the name of the application to : "Flappy Insects".

I changed the name under title and many other options on my google developer console then i published the update... but when i go on the Play Store, it's still appearing as "Flappy Pinkie" and not as "Flappy Insects"..
Don't know what is wrong....

Someone can help me ?

Thank you.

Comment: 1. it takes few hours to update .. 2. you may not use flappy in your app's name for some copyright issues, the app might be removed in future

Comment: Not possible, go and double check on your developer console and it takes 1-2 hours to see updates of it

Comment: i found the error, it was because on "Application Title" under Associated Application tab were false... that's so complicated now with the DEV Console... we have to change the title of the application everywhere !!

Comment: Everybody's making a Flappy Bird clone these days...

Answer (score 0):

As per recent updates in google play store apps that try to clone or use the structural view of a popular app gets removed from the play store ASAP. If in case it still exists further updates may not be possible.

Comment: Yes,they were a media hype all over here are few 1.http://edition.cnn.com/2014/02/17/tech/mobile/flappy-apps-banned/ 2.http://www.theverge.com/2014/2/16/5416774/apple-and-google-fighting-flappy-bird-clones

Comment: Yes that is for Flappy keyword not for clone any other app. Right ?

Comment: Well its for all the apps that clone a major app, just provided with the relevant link based on the current context.